# Is there a good explorer tool Azure Tables?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there a good explorer tool for Azure Tables?

The one from Visual Studio is poor in options - it allows only typing in a query.

Thanks.

Comment: I have marked this question to be closed as it doesn't really fit here but you may find this blog post useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/03/11/windows-azure-storage-explorers-2014.aspx.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Azure Storage Explorer is free and perfectly good.  You pay for what you get but I find it acceptable.

Comment: Please don't answer recommendation questions.

Comment: thanks, i didnt know about it...